# Phaser3 + ES6 classes : how to keep the scope from create to update

Tags: javascript, scope, phaser-framework, es6-class

I'm a beginner in Phaser 3 dev and I'm trying to define a good pattern for all my games. I found a lot of excellent one-page tutorials but when I translate them in the ES6 classes system, I'm having a hard time with scope issue (elements defined in create() aren't visible in update).

I've seen that one common pattern without ES6 classes is to add the methods in the scene property of the game config object like this :

```
scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update : update
}
```

Now here's my question. If I have this code :

```
window.onload = function() {
    const config = {
        width: 1136,
        height: 640,
        backgroundColor: "#ECF0F1",
        scene: bootGame
    }
    jeu = new Phaser.Game(config);

    class bootGame extends Phaser.Scene{
        constructor(){
            super("BootGame");
        }
        preload(){}
        create(){    
            let cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        }
        update(){
            if (cursors.left.isDown){// cursors not defined}
        }
     }
```

What should I write to get "cursors" to be defined in update() ?

Many thanks for your help!

PS: I've seen that question [Phaser + Typescript losing scope in update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991649/phaser-typescript-losing-scope-in-update) but it's Typescript + import module syntax gets me lost in the way.

Comment: Use an instance property, not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootGame` is class and in class `this` refers to that class. So, you need to create `this.cursors` so it becomes the property of that class and every method(function) in the same class can access that property by `this.cursors`.

When you define variable with `let` it's scope is limited to the block it is defined in. Here, you have defined `cursors` in `create` function so it cannot be accessed outside `create` function.